# Remove duplicated rows in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

I have a table with the following structure

```
[id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[account_number] [int] NOT NULL,
[account_name] [varchar(100)] NULL,
[account_chapter] [varchar(20)] NULL,
```

There can be many rows with the same account_number, but differents account_name and account_chapters.

For example, we can have something like the following :

```
id  account_number  account_name  account_chapter
12  1111              Name01        chapter01
13  1111              Name02        chapter02
14  2222              Name03        chapter07
15  2222              Name05        chapter11
16  7777              Name06        chapter44
```

What i want is a query that for each account_number, filter only the first occurence in the table. For example, the query above must be transformed in the following :

```
id  account_number  account_name  account_chapter
12  1111              Name01        chapter01
14  2222              Name03        chapter07
16  7777              Name06        chapter44
```

Here is the query i wrote :

```
with req01 as (select distinct account_number from accounts)
select * from req01 full join (select  * from accounts) as p on p.account_number = req01.account_number
```

It do not produce the expected result.

Any help ?
Thanks.

Comment: If your `id` is an identity, why is it repeated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```sql
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES *
FROM accounts
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY account_number ORDER BY account_chapter);
```

Or, using `ROW_NUMBER` in a more typical way:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY account_number
                                 ORDER BY account_chapter) rn
    FROM accounts
)

SELECT id, account_number, account_name, account_chapter
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Note that both of these answers assumes that the `account_chapter` version determines which of the "duplicates" is actually first.

Answer (score -1):

Normally, the "first" occurrence in the table would be determined by a date/time or identity column.  You have only the identity, so you seem to want:

```
select a.*
from accounts a
where a.id = (select min(a2.id)
              from accounts a2
              where a2.account_number = a.account_number
             );
```